# Sent bitcoin with no fee, waited and bitcoins disappeared

Tags: transactions, wallet, bitcoin-core, transaction-fees, unconfirmed-transactions

I sent about $425 to an adress from my bitcoin-qt wallet and forgot to include a fee. So I googled and googled and waited around for 4 or 5 days for it to stop broadcasting but I get on my computer today to check my transaction on blockchain and its not found anymore. My bitcoin wallet is empty and on the transaction log its status is still "0/unconfirmed". What do I do to get my coins back?!

Answer (score 3):

Export the private key of the address with the stuck transaction, import the PK into something like Electrum, and transfer the entire balance to another of your addresses.

Comment: If the transaction didn't confirm, the funds never moved.

Comment: Alright so I got the private key imported into Electrum and my history on electrum states that the bitcoins were recieved to the address and then sent to the address which I sent them to which still leaves me with 0 bitcoin balance in my electrum wallet. Are there any other suggestions?

Comment: And the wallet that i sent the bitcoins to says that the bitcoins i sent are pending and have 0 confirmations.

Comment: @David: I thought it might be a problem with bitcoin-qt not updating to remove the stuck transaction from its memory pool. Hence the advice to try to force a send from the same address using a different wallet (it's faster than a rescan).
It sounds like the transaction is still hanging around in the memory pool of some relay nodes, even if blockchain.info has forgotten it. Try waiting a couple of days longer and see what happens.

Comment: @420blzit, Is the problem still there?

Comment: I know comments are not suppost to say "thank you", but sometimes a +1 just doesn't do it. Last night my father recovered his bitcoins that were lost for a year, by importing the private key into the blockchain.info wallet.

Answer (score 0):

Your wallet thinks the coins are spent, yet they're stuck in limbo. According to this [bitcointalk post](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5302436.0), you can force the TX to be dropped from your mempool, and then you'll get back the balance:

> If the transaction is associated with your wallet, you can do one of two things:
> *restart bitcoin with the -zapwallettxes option. This will cause bitcoin core to 'forget' all transactions associated with your wallet, and rescan the blockchain for transactions associated with addresses in your wallet.
> *use the RPC command removeprunedfunds, which will remove the transaction from your wallet.
>
> Please note that removing a transaction from your mempool will not affect any other node's mempool, and your transaction can still confirm in the future as long as it is valid.